# CRON doesn't run tasks because "/bin/bash: /var/log/cron.log: Permission denied"

Tags: bash, permissions, cron, log

I have the following CRON task:

```
MAILTO="my@email.com"

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: projectname
30 4 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/project_production/releases/20150305135322 && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Invoices.run_update'\'' >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: projectname
```

But when I take a look on the report that is sent to my email address from the server, there's just following:

```
/bin/bash: /var/log/cron.log: Permission denied
```

(the path to the log file is proper)

Which permissions do I have to set for log files of CRON jobs?

Thank you, have a nice day.

**EDIT:**
there is no `cron.allow` or `cron.deny` file in the `/etc` directory.

**EDIT2;**
Tried `sudo chmod u+w cron.log`, but still the same.

Comment: How did you create the cron task? as a user crontab (`crontab -e`) or as a root crontab (`sudo crontab -e`)?

Comment: The CRON tab was created by a gem from Ruby on Rails. The Rails application use the user called `deployer`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it can't create the log file.  Check the permissions of /var/log folder. It should be

```
ls -l /var/

drwxrwxr-x 18 root syslog   4096 Mar  6 14:30 log
```

If it doesn't look like the first starting with the drwxrwxr-x, change the permissions to the folder by typing in the following:

```
sudo chmod 775 /var/log
```

Run the cron job again.

Comment: Hi Terrance, thank you for your message. The file is in the directory `/var/log`. The permissions: `-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm    25621 Mar  6 22:17 cron.log`. I also tested `cat cron.log` and got this: `cat: cron.log: Permission denied`.

Comment: Change the permissions of the file to match.  There may be a change that adm is not running the cron job.  

`sudo chmod 660 /var/log/cron.log`

Comment: Or just open up the file so everything can write to it.

`sudo chmod 666 /var/log/cron.log`

Comment: Or run `chown <userThatRunsTheCronJob> /var/log/cron.log` - e.g. `chown deployer:deployer /var/log/cron.log`

Comment: Thank you guys! Now, I can `cat` the file, let's see tonight if the CRON task will be proceeded.